# Remote WMI as Administrator on Windows 8

Tags: process, wmi, remoting, remote-access

I am trying to connect to a remote machine and run a script that gets me the OS-es from that machine. To do this I connect through WMI, run cmd /c bcdedit -v > bcd.txt. For some reason I keep getting access denied, the same thing as running bcdedit from a non-administrator account. 
The WMI Security is set, that is running notepad or calc works perfectly. The user which is logged on, and which is used to connect to the machine is the Administrator. I'm stuck at this for days without any solution. Any workaround is welcome.

Note: OS in question is Windows 8
Note2: Workarounds tried(and failed): running another process that schedules a task with bcdedit(access denied), trying to set the process to run as administrator from the properties box(couldn't even start from WMI remotely)

Answer (score 1):

Local admin account and network admin account are two different authorities.
You can access system BCD using local admin account or any account having needed access tokens.

I am not sure the information is available over SNMP.

Another way is to allow remote access to registry 
and decode information from local \HKLM\BCD00000000 branch (mirrors system BCD).

Comment: It seems that on Windows 8 security is more restrictive and it blocks everything that I try to do in order to access bcdedit. Also, another thing that I use in my program is to take the local path of share(through WMI). When querying the sharepath on win8, it returns null. I'm still not sure how I will get past this, but still looking, hopefully something will pop up